# Accessing a variable from an event's subscriber method in another method?

Tags: c#, variables, event-handling

How can I access the variable `line` in the following subscriber method from another method within the same class:

```
private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string line = port.ReadExisting();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a field in the class. You cannot access local variables in methods.

After all, classes are data containers and methods act on that data. local variables are just helpers to that end. If they are needed as state in the class, then make them a field.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a method from the event and pass line to it, it will start the process on the line if required when event it triggered.

```
private void portdatareceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string line = port.ReadExisting();

   SomeMethod(line);
}
```

Other possible way is to declare the line on class scope and use timer control to pool its value to do appropriate action when event is trigger but it may need some locking as well.